# How to monitor access attempts to files with no user permissions

Tags: python, linux, daemon

I wrote a script using inotify that monitors the file system, and runs another script when access to that file is attempted.
Unfortunately, inotify has no way to check if the user is trying to open a file with no user permissions.
I need to detect such an action. This particular script will be running as a daemon script.

Here is the script (daemon script).
It only detects actions regarding files which the user already has permissions for.

```
import inotify.adapters
import os

# path to the lock file
lock_file_path = "./lockfile.txt"

# path to the Unlock.py script
unlock_script_path = "./grant.py"

def is_file_locked(file_path):
    # check if the file is listed in the lock file
    with open(lock_file_path, "r") as lock_file:
        locked_files = lock_file.read().splitlines()
        return file_path in locked_files

def on_write_event(event):
    # check if the written file is locked
    full_file_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(path,filename))
    print(full_file_path)
    if is_file_locked(full_file_path):
        # run the Unlock.py script
        os.system(f"python3 {unlock_script_path}")

# create the inotify event listener
notifier = inotify.adapters.Inotify()
notifier.add_watch("./test",mask=inotify.constants.IN_OPEN)

# listen for the WRITE event
for event in notifier.event_gen(yield_nones=False):
    (_, type_names, path, filename) = event
    print('-')
    if "IN_OPEN" in type_names:
        on_write_event(event)
```

Comment: I think you should look at `auditd` https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/220250/using-auditd-to-capture-permission-denied-notices

Comment: Yes, but dosen't auditd require sudo execution? I'm not sure how that'll work out as a daemon process. I mean, it'll run recursively and sudo requires password entry every time. (I'm making this application for other users, so I'm avoiding things like password less sudo)

Comment: "dosen't auditd require sudo execution" not sudo per se.  It would be started as a system process, not by your application.  "I'm making this application for other users" it would be installed as a dependency, like python or the inotify setup of your current implementation.